# WPF how to change which window opens first

Tags: c#, wpf, window

Im using WPF to make a simple budget app for myself as practice and I can't figure out how to change which window opens first. I mean when you start the program , right now it opens the MainWindow, but I want it to open another window. I have tried this in my app.xaml.cs file:

```
  public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender , StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        GetNameWindow getNameWindow = new GetNameWindow();
        getNameWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

which I read was a way to do it but it doesn't work for me. I'm using c# and visual studio 2017. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at app.xaml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the startup window, open `App.xaml` and replace `"MainWindow.xaml"` with your window:

```
StartupUri="GetNameWindow.xaml">
```

For what you were trying to do, you would need to remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` and instead use `Startup="App_Startup"` and then it would call your event Handler at startup.